# DjangoFilterBackend field = null

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filters

I used DjangoFilterBackend with all fields:

```
class EntitiesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitiesSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = '__all__'
```

It worked perfectly for querying through the url of one or more fields with fixed or boolean values.

like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/persons/?news_by_email=True
http://localhost:8000/api/persons/?issuer=SSP-SC
```

But I need to also filter for fields with null value and it is not working.

I tried:

```
/persons/?parent=null
/persons/?parent=Null
/persons/?parent=NULL
/persons/?parent=
/persons/?parent__isnull
```

Any suggestions in this same simplified process?

Any suggestions that require an extension or new viewset?

Comment: what about `/persons/?parent=None`?

Answer (score 7):

You may also want to query the 'exact' value, besides isnull. In that case,

```
filter_fields = {'parent': ['exact', 'isnull']}
```

And you can make a query with '=True',

```
/persons/?parent__isnull=True
```

Answer (score 3):

```
filter_fields = {'parent': ['isnull']}
```

This will add a filter with 'isnull' and you can make a query as below:

```
/persons/?parent__isnull=true
```

Comment: Note that filter_fields is now filterset_fields but yes, this works fine. Add [ 'exact', 'isnull' ] if you also want to be able to filter on the underlying exact value.