# How to filter by not empty string in a Django Rest Framework request querysting?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As per title, given a model that has a string field like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
```

I can configure a generic api with filters in Django Test Framework like this:

```
class MyModelApi(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    model = MyModel    
    filterset_fields = ('name')
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend)
    querystring = MyModel.objects.all()
```

This allows me to filter the api like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/my_api?name=foo
```

I also know how to configure such api so that it is possible to use filters different from the `exact` one like:

```
http://localhost:5000/my_api?name__iconstains=bar
```

What I cannot figure out is: how to get all the `MyModel` object *whose `name` field is **not** an empty list*? I've tried the following with no results:

```
http://localhost:5000/my_api?name__gt=
http://localhost:5000/my_api?name=
```

Comment: did you try the answer for the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319957/djangofilterbackend-field-null

Comment: Here is an example using custom filter to solve this issue https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/tips.html#filtering-by-empty-values

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/my_api?name__in=,
```

It basically articulates a search which should always match on non-empty `name`s.